# Python - If string in dictionary, else add to dictionary and add index

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to run a program where a number (as a string) is provided in a variable, an if statement checks for that string in a dictionary, and if it is not found it prompts to create a name for that number which becomes the index in the dictionary for that variable. So the code will look something like this:

```
pnumber = raw_input('Input number here: ')
contacts = {}
if pnumber in contacts: #not sure how to do this
     next_method()
else:
     name = raw_input("Input name for this number: ")
     #add name, pnumber as entry to dictionary
```

Any help working this out further would be fantastic. Very new to this so let me know if there is anything I should change to this request.

Comment: You might want to go through [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) section of the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to check and ask for name only when you don't have the number, you could use the following to do this once:

```
contacts = {}
pnumber = raw_input('Input number here: ')
if pnumber not in contacts: #not sure how to do this
    name = raw_input("Input name for this number: ")
    contacts[pnumber] = name
```

To do it multiple (say 10) times, just use a loop at the top:

```
contacts = {}
for _ in range(10):
    pnumber = raw_input('Input number here: ')
    if pnumber not in contacts: #not sure how to do this
        name = raw_input("Input name for this number: ")
        contacts[pnumber] = name
```